# Windows Service Application C#

Tags: windows, service, c#

Здравствуйте, уважаемые программисты!

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
В С# я новичек, только изучаю. Создаю Service приложение.

Цель проги: при запуске службы выводить значек в области уведомлений с оповещение что прога запустилась.

В дизайнере кидаю notifyIcon. В коде пишу:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");

        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon  = ToolTipIcon.Info;
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Remote ADSL Reboot";
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText  = "Программа запущена! :)";
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In onStop.");

        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Remote ADSL Reboot";
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Программа остановлена! :(";
    }
```

Добавил инсталлятор. Служба устанавливается нормально. Служба запускается нормально, но никаких уведомлений не появляется.

Если руками запустить exe файл проги, то значок появляется в области уведомлений, но менее чем через минуту вылетает с ошибкой:

> Cannot start service from command line or a debugger. A windows Service mus be installed (using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Service Administrative tool or NET START command.

Хотя сервис запущен.

Подскажите, что не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Службы Windows не имеют пользовательского интерфейса и работают в отдельном сеансе (работают в отдельной оконной станции). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.80).aspx
В данном случае лучше сделать отдельное приложение с GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Службу Windows нельзя запускать непосредственно как приложение - только через диспетчер служб. Попробуйте указать в настройках своей службы галочку "Разрешить службе взаимодействовать с рабочим столом".